# Using xhtml2pdf, replace hyperlinks with actual links

Tags: python, hyperlink, xhtml2pdf

I was wondering if anyone could instruct as how to replace hyperlinks with their actual html links using xhtml2pdf. So if I had a hyperlink in the PDF I created that read:

```
Google
```

It would replace it with:

```
<http://www.google.com>
```

This is the current simple function I am using:

```
import os
import sys
import cgi
import cStringIO
import logging

import xhtml2pdf.pisa as pisa

pisa.showLogging()

def testSimple(
    data = open('FILENAME').read(),
    dest="test.pdf":

    pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(
        cStringIO.StringIO(data),
        file(dest, "wb")
        )

    if pdf.err:
        dumpErrors(pdf)
    else:
        pisa.startViewer(dest)

testSimple()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common requirement for print styles of web sites, where people cannot click the link but need to type it.

It can [actually be achieved with CSS](http://davidwalsh.name/optimize-your-links-for-print-using-css-show-url):

```
a:link:after, a:visited:after { content:" [" attr(href) "] "; }
```

It will depend on the CSS implementation of xhtmltopdf if this will work in your case, though.

You can use [CSS selectors](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets/Selectors) if you only want to apply this to certain links, for example

```
a.printable:link:after,
a.printable:visited:after {
    content:" [" attr(href) "] ";
}
```

will only affect links that have that class:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" class="printable">Stack Overflow</a>
```

Comment: This worked! However, I'm wondering if there is a method for displaying these only for certain tags.  Can this be pasted inside a specific tag css element?

Comment: How exactly do you mean? Not for all links? You can use any more specific CSS selectors that xhtmltopdf supports. I added an example for a simple `class` on the link tag.

Comment: Which version of XHtml2pdf are you using ?